# Video player to stream video as it downloads

Tags: python, video, stream, wxpython

I am writing a wxPython application which connects to a large (2Gb+) video file and downloads the file in chunks. I have been using wx.media.MediaCtrl to play the file once it is downloaded and externally calling `avconv` to split the video file into audio and video. Once the file is split I perform some basic voice recognition and display the returned results at the correct time while the video is playing.

What I want to do is adapt the application, so that the processing takes place whilst the file is still downloading, and I have hit a bit of a hurdle about how to get started. I am looking for suggestions as to how to get started. So far I have a thread which starts the download and buffers a chunk of the file at a time. I need a python player which will allow me to append each chunk of data in memory and update the player so that the available video gets longer. I am sure that `wx.media.MediaCtrl` wont let me do this as it only seems to support loading video files from disk. I also need ideas as to how to split the audio from the video whilst it is downloading and how I can store it in memory. I am looking for pure python ideas, as I don't want to write the data to disk.

In essence I need to achieve a video player that populates as the file is downloaded and gives access to the audio stream as it downloads...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to split the file into small parts (part1, part2, part3 ect...) tell the video player to play part1 first, part2 and later join the files that are have already been played (Refer to [Play mp3 file while downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536711/play-mp3-file-while-downloading))