# android MediaPlayer - playing from Http stream

Tags: android, asynchronous, media-player

i am writing a small player that can play from Http. media player can play mp3 from http stream with **mPlayer.setDataSource(url);** , but i want to save this file. I tried following:

```
public static void downloadFile(File f, String songUrl, IDownloadListener listener)throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL(songUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

    Integer fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
    try {
        byte data[] = new byte[16384];

        int lastPercentNotify = -1, curPercent;
        int count;
        int total = 0;

        listener.onFileDescriptorAvailable(outStream.getFD());   //!!!! this willnotify about FD

        while ((count = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1){
            total += count;
            outStream.write(data, 0, count);
            curPercent = (total * 100) / fileLength;

            if (curPercent != lastPercentNotify && listener != null && curPercent % 10 == 0){
                listener.onDownload(f.getName(), curPercent, 100);
                lastPercentNotify = curPercent;
            }
        }
    }finally {
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

where in my listener i do following:

```
 mPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescr);
//prepare and call mPlayer.start()
```

But i have various exceptions when i am trying to change the point when i am getting the descriptor.

**UPD:** My code works fine for saving file. My trouble the playing mp3 and saving in to the sdcard in the same time.

Comment: [Use This To Save Mp3 File In sd card Also add Permissain][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133498/how-to-download-mp3-file-in-android-from-a-url-and-save-it-in-sd-card-here-is

Comment: My code works fine for saving file. My trouble the playing mp3 and saving in to the sdcard in the same time.

Comment: on my exprience u can save but after save u can play mp3 from sd card first time u play from Url and secand time U Play from Sd Card

Comment: I know it, it is easy. But i want to do it in the same time. Thats why i asked in this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536711/play-mp3-file-while-downloading

Comment: THX for link, maybe i will use the AudioTrack class.